# how to build dynamic call to javascript function using asp.net mvc and knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, hottowel

I am building a mvc aplication using as template HotTowel (you know, durandal, knockout, breeze,etc). The application is not ready yet we are doing good progress :).
At the middle of one funcionality I need to build a dynamic call to javascript function.
The call using hard code values is something like:

```
<a href="#" id="openreport"                                                 
onclick="showReport('@Url.Action("Index","Report", new { Id= 9, languageId = 2})');">Show  
report</a>
```

The call abover works fine. My troubles start when i try using knockoutjs to bind onclick event to string property. something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="openReport" data-bind="onclick: $root.reportUrl()"  > 
 Show report
```

where report url it's a obervable variable. here the typescript code:

```
export var reportUrl =<any> ko.observable();

export var expandRow = function (myObjectComeFromATable) {

    var urlAction = '@Url.Action("Index", "Report", new { Id= ID_TO_REPLACE, languageId = LANG_TO_REPLACE }) ';
    var url = "showReport('"+urlAction+"');";
    reportUrl(url);   
};
```

**UPDATE**
Use of quotes are fine. the value of the knockout variable is same has hard code value showed before. Maybe it's a aproblem with my sintaxis in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to eval code in an observable? I don't think it will work. You could do the eval manually in a function. But I don't think that's a good solution.

If you always call "showReport" on click, you don't need an eval: just have a property in your model that contains the url to call, and run showReport(yourUrl) in a callback function.

If the function you are calling on click changes, you could keep a reference to the function to call in your model. Something like that (but cleaner):

```
var model = function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.function1 = function() {
         alert('hello');   
    }
    this.function2 = function() {
         alert('world');   
    }
    this.run = function() {
         _this.current(); 
    }
    this.change = function() {
         _this.current = _this.function2;   
    }

    this.current = this.function1;
}
ko.applyBindings(new model());


<a href="#" data-bind="click: run">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: change">Switch</a>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/pp2QA/2/